# Can't loop through a matrix of values in Python

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have the following code:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import linalg as LA

G = nx.read_graphml('/home/user/Documents/J_Data/brain_1.graphml')

Z = nx.to_numpy_matrix(G)

e_vals, e_vecs = LA.eigh(Z)

for x in range(0, len(e_vals)):
    e_vecs_new[:, :x] = e_vecs[:, :x]*delta[:x]

print e_vecs_new
```

and when I run this code it seems the for loop does not run properly. It is meant to iterate through each column of e_vecs and set that whole column to 0 based on the value in delta(0 or 1). The terminal output is the following:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/PycharmProjects/Graph_Project/Graph.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amit/PycharmProjects/Graph_Project/Graph.py", line 37, in <module>
    e_vecs_new[:, :x] = e_vecs[:, :x]*delta[:x]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 341, in __mul__
    return N.dot(self, asmatrix(other))
ValueError: matrices are not aligned

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I run one iteration of the intended loop:

```
print e_vecs[:, :1]*delta[:1]
```

I get the desired output, which is a column of 0's of the appropriate length:

```
[[ 0.]
 [ 0.]
.
.
.
 [ 0.]
 [ 0.]]
```

When I run the following print statements:

```
print e_vecs_new.shape
print e_vecs.shape
print delta.shape
```

I get the following output:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/user/PycharmProjects/Graph_Project/Graph.py
(242, 242)
(242, 242)
(242,)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does the fact that delta's shape is (242,) instead of (242,1) an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `delta` is just a vector you should just be indexing into it as `delta[x]`

`delta[:1]` works because you're asking for just the first element, but delta[:2] will be more than a single integer, and so the multiplication is interpreted as a dot product.

```
>>> delta = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> delta[:1]
array([1])
>>> delta[:2]
array([1, 2])
```

etc